# Spring Boot Application getting warning , how to fix this and this warning will affect in production?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven

WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils (file:/C:/Users/Lalith/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.2.8.RELEASE/spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

How can I fix this?
This warning will affect in production?

Answer (score 1):

I see these WARNING on `JAVA 9+` setup.

Looks like it was a [known issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/21385) for some version of Spring.

Some suggest to remove `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools` dependency in `pom.xml`

It won't cause any issue in production. But yes in future if you upgrade version might affect as mentioned in WARNING.

> WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future
> release

Comment: remove `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools` dependency worked for me